# Selecting only CFSR images in Google Earth Engine with precipitation data

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, precipitation

I am trying to create cumulative monthly composites of precipitation from CFSR data in Google Earth Engine (i.e. each image would be mm/month for each month)

However, I realised that images ending with 'F00' do not have the precipitation band I need - Total_precipitation_surface_3_Hour_Accumulation - whereas those with 'F03' has that band.

As such, when I try creating an image collection of images with that specific band only, it pulls up the error: 'Pattern 'Total_precipitation_surface_3_Hour_Accumulation' did not match any bands'

How can I go about choosing only the images ending with the name 'F03'?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CFSR')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-04-01', '2019-05-31'))
                  .map(function (image) { return image.clip(roi)})
                  .select('Total_precipitation_surface_3_Hour_Accumulation');
                  
print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hour is saved in the property `forecast_hour` of every Image. You can use this property and `.filterMetadata()` to filter only those with `forecast_hour: 3`. Here's the code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CFSR')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-04-01', '2019-05-31'))
                  .filterMetadata("forecast_hour", "equals", 3)
                  .map(function (image) { return image.clip(roi)})
                  .select('Total_precipitation_surface_3_Hour_Accumulation');
                  
print(dataset)
```